# Making program to stop reading from file if EOF and read only from other

Tags: c, conditional-statements

Only problem is that when one file is at EOF, program still writes - or +, just need to make some condition to make it just takes words from one file when other is at EOF. For example

> **prvy.txt:** Ahojte nasi studenti ktori maju radi programovanie
>
> **druhy.txt:** vsetci mili
>
> **treti.txt:**
>   +Ahojte -vsetci +nasi -mili +studenti +ktori +maju +radi +programovanie

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE *first, *second, *third;
    char ch[256],ch1[256];
    int i=1,count=0, ch2;
    char space = ' ';
    char minus = '-';
    char plus = '+';

    first=fopen("prvy.txt", "r");
    second=fopen("druhy.txt", "r");
    third=fopen("treti.txt", "w");

    if(first==NULL || second==NULL || third==NULL)
    {
        perror("error");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fscanf(first, "%255s", ch) == 1)
    {
        count++;
    }

    while (fscanf(second, "%255s", ch) == 1)
    {
        count++;
    }

    printf("%d",count);

    rewind(first);
    rewind(second);

    for(i;i<=count;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==1)
        {
            fputc(plus,third);
            ch2=fgetc(first);
            while(ch2 != EOF && ch2 != ' ' && ch2 != '\n') {
                putc(ch2,third);
                ch2=fgetc(first);
            }
        }
        else if(i%2==0)
        {

            fputc(minus,third);
            ch2=fgetc(second);
            while(ch2 != EOF && ch2 != ' ' && ch2 != '\n') {
                putc(ch2,third);
                ch2=fgetc(second);
            }
        }
        putc(space,third);
    }   

    fclose(first);
    fclose(second);
    fclose(third);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `count` contain? (hint: `no. words in first + no. words in second`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will alternate between the two files. That will not work as the files may contain different number of words.

One solution could be to count the words in one variable per file. Then the loop could be something like:

```
 // count1: number of words in first file
 // count2: number of words in second file
while(count1 > 0 || count2 > 0)
{
    if (count1 > 0)
    {
        fputc(plus,third);
        ch2=fgetc(first);
        while(ch2 != EOF && ch2 != ' ' && ch2 != '\n') {
            putc(ch2,third);
            ch2=fgetc(first);
        }
        --count1;
    }

    if (count2 > 0)
    {
        fputc(minus,third);
        ch2=fgetc(second);
        while(ch2 != EOF && ch2 != ' ' && ch2 != '\n') {
            putc(ch2,third);
            ch2=fgetc(second);
        }
        --count2;
    }

    putc(space,third);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to scan both files first to get a count. Instead, create an array of two input files and use an index to toggle between both as you read. When a file is exhausted when its turn has come, scan and print the other one.

That way, you get rid of the need to control the succesful input of two files simultaneously:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *in[2];                        // Two alternating input files
    FILE *out;

    char line[80];
    char prefix[] = "+-";               // Alternating signs, +/-
    int index = 0;                      // index to in[] and prefix[]

    in[0] = fopen("1.txt", "r");
    in[1] = fopen("2.txt", "r");
    out = fopen("3.txt", "w");

    if (!(in[0] && in[1] && out)) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fscanf(in[index], "%79s", line) == 1) {
        fprintf(out, "%c%s ", prefix[index], line);

        index = !index;
    }

    while (fscanf(in[!index], "%79s", line) == 1) {
        fprintf(out, "%c%s ", prefix[!index], line);
    }

    fclose(in[0]);
    fclose(in[1]);
    fclose(out);

    return 0;
}
```